# Quelle serait une meilleure façon de dire « Je suis le seul d’entre mes frères à avoir été l’objet de moqueries en rapport avec mon poids »?

Tags: choix-de-mot, constructions, lexique, formulation

J’aimerais qu’on me présente d’autres énonciations (plus élégantes dans la mesure du possible, à tout le moins plus concises peut-être) exprimant la même idée que la phrase citée en question.

Comment: Pour mettre en exergue la cause des moqueries : « À cause de mon poids, je suis le seul de mes frères à [ avoir subi des moqueries | s'être fait moquer de moi ] ».

Comment: @Personne Il y a certainement quelque chose qui cloche dans la phrase « _À cause de mon poids, je suis le seul de mes frères à s'être fait moquer de moi._ » : le pronom « moi ».

Comment: @LPH — Il est vrai que les pur·e·s littéraires auraient supprimé *de moi*. « Je me suis fait moquer par mes frères » lorsqu'il s'agit dune raillerie sur le comportement, mais l'attaque *ad hominem* déclenche une douleur silencieuse au plus profond de l'être, elle rejaillit ici dans ces deux derniers mots.

Comment: @Personne Le souci avec cette tournure, c'est qu'elle implique que les autres frères n'ont jamais subi de moquerie qu'elle qu'en soit la cause. Alors que rien dans la phrase de l'auteur n'indique qu'un autre frère n'a pas subi des moqueries sur sa taille, par exemple. :)

Comment: @Reyedy … en effet, si cette situation se présente, on peut ajouter « … de moi *à ce sujet* » ou simplement remplacer "et moi" par *à ce sujet*.

Comment: @Personne Je ne suis pas convaincu que: *je suis le seul de mes frères* résiste à l'analyse, puisque ce *je* ne fait pas partie de l'ensemble *mes frères*, d'autre part *s'être fait* implique il me semble un pronom de la troisième personne: *le seul à s'être fait moquer de **lui***. Cela dit, la phrase est quand même parfaitement compréhensible, ce qui est l'essentiel !

Comment: @jlliagre … *de lui*, il parle comme Alain Delon ?  c'est de la grammaire pure, ma première réponse révèle ce que les conventions cache dans la bonne société,

Comment: @Personne Pour employer "de moi", il faudrait plutôt écrire "le seul à m'être fait moquer de moi".

Comment: @Jean-LouFrenette — Je vote pour cette solution, je me suis laissé embarqué par le *à* de la première proposition  :-)

Comment: @Personne *Le seul à s'être fait moquer de moi* est très discutable, puisque personne d'autre que moi ne peut se faire "moquer de moi". On peut régler ce problème avec *Je suis le seul dont on s'est moqué*, mais l'autre problème reste pendant...

Comment: @Jilliagre..."De notre fratrie" était sous-entendu, je voulais seulement porter l'attention sur la faute à corriger... Si nous sommes trois frères, je propose d'opter pour cette formulation: Je suis le seul des trois dont on s'est moqué. Bien évidemment seul le contexte permettrait de préciser la nature de la relation qui unit les trois personnes en question.

Comment: @jiliagre...Je viens de percevoir la nuance...

Comment: @jlliagre … cela complète ma dernière réponse à *Jean-LouFrenette*. Ce qui m'interpelle dans l'aide que vous venez de m'apporter : la spontanéité de ma première et dernière réponse a recueilli votre attention. PS : pouvez-vous [ou un modérateur] ouvrir une suite dans une *room* dédiée à cette question dans Cosette, sans enlever les précédents commentaires qui relèvent de la question ?

Comment: @Personne Je n'ai pas ce pouvoir, il me faudrait je crois 500k de réputation... J'y travaille ;-)

Comment: @Personne Oui, j'avais mal compris ton commentaire. Je croyais que tu voulais que certains anciens commentaires soient placés dans cette nouvelle *room*.

Comment: @Personne Je ne sais pas si c'est un lapsus ou voulu mais j'aime bien le "je s'opprimerai" ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Je suis le seul d’entre mes frères à avoir été l’objet de moqueries en rapport avec mon poids.*

J'ai l'impression qu'il existe un  nombre inimaginable de façon de tourner une phrase pour exprimer la même idée ; j'en ai réunies huit ci-dessous. Cependant, je ne peux pas conclure qu'il y en ait une seule de laquelle on puisse sans aucun doute dire qu'elle soit plus élégante. Le seul reproche qu'on puisse faire à cette phrase, peut-être, ce serait la locution « d'entre » ; on la trouve assez rarement dans la langue moderne, comme on peut le vérifier [ici](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22d%27entre%22&lr=lang_fr&safe=active&tbs=lr:lang_1fr&tbm=bks&ei=NmL3X_X6MbGBjLsPu6OisAk&start=0&sa=N&ved=0ahUKEwj17YOzyIruAhWxAGMBHbuRCJY4ZBDy0wMI8QY&biw=1920&bih=1005&dpr=1) et il semblerait qu'elle ne soit plus perçue comme aussi explicite que par le passé. Ce n'est donc pas vraiment d'un manque d'élégance qu'il faudrait parler. Un problème grave, cependant, c'est que le narrateur ne se trouve pas parmi ses frères.

- De mes frères et moi je suis le seul duquel on se soit moqué à cause de son poids.
- On ne s'est jamais moqué de mes frères à cause de leur poids, je suis le seul à avoir dû supporter ce genre de moquerie.
- J'ai dû supporter des moqueries à cause de mon poids, ce qui n'a jamais été le cas pour/de/en ce qui concerne mes frères.
- À cause de mon poids, j'ai eu à supporter des moqueries, cependant, mes frères, jamais.
- En rapport à l'obésité on n'a jamais moqué mes frères, seulement moi.
- Mes frères n'ont jamais eu à subir de moquerie en rapport avec leur obésité, ce qui n'est pas mon cas.
- On ne s'est jamais moqué de mes frères parce qu'ils étaient obèses, de moi si.
- L'obésité de mes frères ne leur a jamais nui dans le sens de causer qu'on se moque d'eux, mais je ne peux pas en dire autant.

Comment: Les propositions 2, 3 et 4 sont en français soutenu et ont l'élégance de la simplicité. Les suivantes déplacent le problème de l'obésité sur les autres, ce qui est une déduction, certes possible, mais pas induite dans la question. Les mots et tournures de la première renvoie aux auteurs d'il y a un siècle, elle est alambiquée, désuète, compassée … imprononçable de nos jours de nos jours.

Comment: À en juger par les tournures que LPH m’a proposées, la tournure « d’entre mes frères » serait boiteuse, n’est-ce pas Personne, étant donné que je ne fais pas partie de mes frères. Il serait, après examen de la question, sûrement mieux d’employer le terme « fratrie » afin de m’inclure dans le groupe concerné.

Comment: Voici donc la phrase repensée: J’ai été le seul de ma fratrie à s’être fait moquer de moi.

Comment: Avec une petite modification : « de lui » au lieu de « de moi ».

Comment: Encore là j’ignore si le terme « fratrie » a la bienveillance de m’intégrer parmi mes frères.

Comment: En effet LPH, tu as raison, tu as souvent raison je dirais même!

Comment: En réponse au commentaire « Encore là j’ignore si le terme « fratrie » a la bienveillance de m’intégrer parmi mes frères.» — Pas de doute, comme on fait toujours partie de sa propre famille.

Comment: @Jean-LouFrenette … j'ai aussi envisagé *fratrie*. Il y a une ambiguïté : souvent les gens incluent aussi les sœurs dans la fratrie (vieil héritage des sociétés patriarcales). Avec ce mot, la formule devient plus soutenue.

Comment: @LPH En relisant l'une de tes propositions, l'une d'entre elles m'a fait hésiter sur l'emploi d'une préposition. Il s'agit de "de" dans la troisième: à mon avis il y a un risque de confusion possible y découlant, je m'explique: le "de" pourrait être interprété comme une façon plus simple d'exprimer "de la part", ce qui changerait complètement l'idée véhiculée par la phrase. Elle exprimerait plutôt l'idée que le narrateur n'a pas subi de moqueries de la part de ses frères, alors qu'en privilégiant l'utilisation de "pour" on se retrouverait avec la signification d'origine, celle escomptée.

Comment: @Jean-LouFrenette Je pense que cette interprétation est impossible, mais il y a une chose que crois vraie, c'est que « pour » a plus de force  que « de » pour exprimer la relation voulue (en ce qui concerne). Donc, « pour » pourrait être utilisé avantageusement.

Comment: @Jean-LouFrenette — Dans la troisième proposition, le choix présenté n'est pas lié à *cas*, mais à *concerne* : l'expression consacrée est ***pour ce qui concerne***.

Comment: @LPH   l'expression consacrée est : *en ce qui **me** concerne* (*me* est absent de votre proposition).

Answer (score 3):

> Contrairement à mes frères, je suis le seul dont le poids ait fait
> l'objet de moqueries.

Answer (score 1):

> J'me suis fait [gazer](https://www.dictionnairedelazone.fr/dictionary/definition/gazer) [grave](https://www.dictionnairedelazone.fr/dictionary/definition/grave) [ma mère](https://www.languefrancaise.net/Bob/77652) que j'étais un sumo, alors que mes [reufs](https://www.dictionnairedelazone.fr/dictionary/search/reuf/reuf), [que tchi](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/que_tchi#fr) !

Comment: (*) sauf en [Tchéquie](https://youtu.be/2Ux8xSKG7xE) !

Comment: @Thélée_Lavoie Qui plus est, est une contrepèterie de Keutchi ;-)

Comment: Vraiment  recherché !

Comment: @LPH Je savais que tu apprécierais !

Comment: À la merci du temps des loges !

Answer (score 0):

> De toute la fratrie, je suis le seul à avoir subi des moqueries sur son poids.

J'aime bien la concision qu'apporte le terme "fratrie" ici. Cependant, comme discuté en commentaires, on perd peut-être l'information selon laquelle la fratrie n'est composée que de garçons. Et en effet, après quelques recherches, je constate qu'il n'existe pas de terme permettant de désigner une fratrie composée exclusivement de garçons ou de filles. À défaut, voici une proposition :

> De toute notre fratrie de garçons, je suis le seul à avoir subi des moqueries sur [s/m]on poids.

Avec une reformulation plus radicale, voici une autre proposition :

> Personne parmi mes frères n'avait subi de moqueries sur son poids, jusqu'à moi.

Le défaut de celle-ci, c'est qu'elle induit une idée de temporalité, et personnellement elle me donne l'idée que le narrateur est le plus jeune frère, ce qui n'est pas nécessairement le cas dans la phrase d'origine.